# Launching MIT Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, edwin

Can you help me to figure out how to use MIT Scheme? The Edwin editor. There is a huge field to type but it doesn't respond. It allows me to evaluate expressions in the bottom tiny field only when I type esc twice in a row.[image]

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual or to use the online help?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes I did. Several times. It didn't help.

Comment: Are you able to do a `Ctrl-x Ctrl-e` to evaluate the `564` shown in your picture? Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-Scheme-Evaluation.html

Comment: @Flux That is the problem. I read it. It doesn't do anything. It just types C(Ctrl)-x in the bottom part instead of 'Evaluate expression:' that is shown in the picture.

Comment: Wondering if this problem is related to windows possibly eating certain control sequences? Your description sounds like the C-x is going through, but maybe not the C-e?

Comment: @JohnClements C-e just brings the pointer from the right to the left and do nothing.

Comment: The only thing that works is M-z

Comment: Wait... from the right to the left, or from the left to the right?

Comment: I'm sorry. From the left to the right.

Comment: I think you should keep the Ctrl key pressed, when hitting `x` and then `e`. do not release the Ctrl in between. are you doing it this way?

Comment: @WillNess Yes, sure. I am doing it that way.

Comment: on Win7 [it works](https://imgur.com/a/fzKEd). both tutorial and info do not though. something's broken.

Comment: if M-z is working then you don't really have a problem, only the inconvenience of having to put naked values into a form, like e.g. `(car (list 564))`.

Comment: Thank you to everybody. Since figuring out that M-z works I have been using M-z and mostly it satisfy my needs. Thanks!

Comment: you can post your own answer and accept it, to signal that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwin is an editor; it is not a interactive shell. The big empty space is used to write a scheme file.
I think you to work in an interactive shell.

Open a console window and type "scheme" to work in an interactive shell.
To write a scheme-program-file you can use an editor in ascii-mode. Use the suffix "scm" to store the file. 
To run it, type in the scheme-shell:

> (load "start.scm")

40 years ago scheme and edwin were distributed by texas instruments. With these tools I started to love programming. Today I am working under ubuntu and I am using emacs as editor and a bash-shell running MIT/Gnu-Scheme. 5 year ago tryed edwin agin, but I preferd emacs.

The most people would suggest to use DrRacket.
What Operation System you are using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Do you write it for ubuntu? Because in windows typing "scheme" brings a response that it is not an internal or external command...

Comment: this answer is wrong. I installed MIT Scheme; typed the code form by form into the same "big empty space" as shown in the question, pressing C-x-e after each, and [it worked](https://imgur.com/a/fzKEd) as an "interactive shell". The only difference is, I installed it on Win-7 box.